# jpa specification with @OneToOne relation

Tags: java, repository, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'd like to use jpa repository with specification

now I have two tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long idUser;

private Area area;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="iduser")
public Long getIdUser() {
return idUser;
}
public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
this.idUser = idUser;
}

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="idarea")
public Area getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(Area area) {
    this.area = area;
}

}
```

and Area Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "area")
public class Area {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="idarea")
private Long idArea;

@Column(name="area_name")
private String areaName;

public Long getIdArea() {
    return idArea;
}

public void setIdArea(Long idArea) {
    this.idArea = idArea;
}

public String getAreaName() {
    return areaName;
}

public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
}

}
```

Then I have user Repository that extens also JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
public interface UserRepository extends   CrudRepository<User,Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

Finally I have a simple specification

```
public class UserSpecification {

public static Specification<User> findByAreaName(final String areaName){
    return new Specification<User>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root,
                CriteriaQuery<?> criteria, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.<String>get("??????"),areaName);
        }
    };

}

}
```

So, my question is :What I have to put in "?????" that is the areaName of table area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
return cb.equal((Path<String>) ((Path<Area>) root.get("area")).get("areaName"),areaName);
```

And you have to make sure, that Area gets loaded, because its lazy.

Edit:
As I mentioned in my comment, maybe just try without casting at all.

I have a method for such cases you can adjust for your needs:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T, R> Path<R> getPath(Class<R> resultType, Path<T> root, String path) {
    String[] pathElements = path.split("\\.");
    Path<?> retVal = root;
    for (String pathEl : pathElements) {
        retVal = (Path<R>) retVal.get(pathEl);
    }
    return (Path<R>) retVal;
}
```

Its called with the dot-notation to get the path. In your case it would be:

```
getPath(String.class, root, "area.areaName");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: maybe just try without casting at all: return cb.equal(root.get("area").get("areaName"),areaName);

Comment: log says org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize now I'm just trying with Static metamodel [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/metamodel.html#metamodel-static) What Do you think about?

Comment: the staticmetamodel is for sure easier than a dynamic Pathexpression. I use an eclipse plugin which performs the generation of these. But maybe your class Area should be Serializable as well.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please short elaborate, what was the cause of your SerializationException?

Comment: no, I dont undestand. I saw that only in specific case the excetpion thrwos. If can you take a look I posted part of the log at this link [exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253403/org-hibernate-type-serializationexception-could-not-deserialize)

Comment: not working in my case !